# How to adjust the height of a view controller in a nav controller?

Tags: ios

How can you adjust the height of a view controller within a nav controller? If the nav controller shows VC1 and the nav controller has a height of 250, how can you make the height 350 once VC2 is pushed. Attached are examples:

[image]
[image]

Comment: use segue identifier from vc2 to and change the height after push occurs!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a storyboard segue you could use:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"SEGUE_ID_HERE"]) {
        //Resize VC Here
    }
}
```

This would be fired BEFORE the nav controller goes to the destination viewcontroller

Comment: Should I change the height of the VC or the nav controller?

Comment: Try chaning the height of the VC or the Nav Controller, try both and let me know which works for you